# The controllers with [Authorize] attribute return unauthorized error but the ones with [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] work perfectly

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-core-mvc

With the following login method and "Startup.cs", the controllers with [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")] attribute work fine but the ones which need an authenticated user and do not care about their roles return "Status Code:401 Unauthorized".

Login method:

```
    public async void LogOn(IUser user, string domain, bool remember, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var context = AccessorsHelper.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        await context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.GetId().ToString())
        };

        claims.AddRange(user.GetRoles().Select(role => new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role)));

        await context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims)),
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = remember,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(timeout)
            });
    }
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.InjectOliveDependencies();

        var builder = services.AddMvc(options => {
            options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new Olive.Mvc.OliveBinderProvider());
            //options.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new TestBinderProvider());
        })
        .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(manager =>
        {
            var oldMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider = manager.FeatureProviders.First(f => f is MetadataReferenceFeatureProvider);
            manager.FeatureProviders.Remove(oldMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider);
            manager.FeatureProviders.Add(new ReferencesMetadataReferenceFeatureProvider());
        }); ;
        //ConfigureMvc(builder);

        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options => {
            options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new ViewLocationExpander());
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IUserStore<User>, UserStore>();
        services.AddSingleton<IRoleStore<string>, RoleStore>();
        services.AddIdentity<User, string>();
        services.AddAuthentication(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.ConfigureOliveDependencies(env);

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            //routes.MapRoute(
            //    name: "default",
            //    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

In addition, I am using ASP.Net Core 2.0.

Comment: Does `LogOn` method really need `[Authorize]` attribute? It should allow anonymous to access everyone tries to logon...

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu My `LogOn` method does not have `[Authotize]` attribute. I just provide the method because I think something should be wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a small change in the LogIn method the problem is fixed.

```
    public async void LogOn(IUser user, string domain, bool remember, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        var context = AccessorsHelper.HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

        await context.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme);

        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultNameClaimType, user.GetId().ToString())
        };

        claims.AddRange(user.GetRoles().Select(role => new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, role)));

        await context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
            new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "AuthenticationType")), // AuthenticationType is just a text and I do not know what is its usage.
            new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = remember,
                ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(timeout)
            });
    }
```

Check the commented part for the change.